# Run Boot time commands in AWS Elastic Container Service(ECS) instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to execute some commands in ECS instances, before the tasks start. Like installing something in EC2 instances. I am using ECS-CLI is there any possible way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where and when do exactly you want to run commands, but you can use [ecs-cli up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-up.html) which has option:

> **--extra-user-data** string - Specifies additional user data for your container instance. Files can be shell scripts or cloud-init directives. They are packaged into a MIME multipart archive along with user data provided by the Amazon ECS CLI that directs instances to join your cluster. For more information, see Specifying User Data.

Comment: I need to run EC2 commands in instances not inside containers. install htop on all instances and pulling specific images with command that is needed externally.

Comment: For example we can specify commands in Elastic beanstatic to be executed before docker containers start.I want that sort of option

Comment: @SridharRaju I'm not aware of such functionality in ECS. You can use user-data as I wrote in the answer, but this is not the same as using ebextentios in EB.